# Debug "Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement" in C# when submitting data to Access Database using OleDbConnection

Tags: c#, database, syntax, oledb

I'm diving head first into both C# and Access databases.  This is all brand new to me, so I have a small test database set up to work with a small template.  I'm trying to figure out why I keep getting a syntax error that is triggered by the ExecuteNonQuery() method.  Any help and insight would be appreciated.

Edit: SOLVED: This is the working code for this situation.  All help was greatly appreciated!

```
    public void addToDb()
    {
        String first = "John";
        String last = "Doe";
        String testPath = GVar.TEST_FILEPATH + GVar.TEST_DATABASE;
        String strCommand = "INSERT INTO ID ([First], [Last]) Values(@First, @Last)";
        OleDbConnection dbTest = null;
        OleDbCommand cmd = null;

        try
        {
            dbTest = new OleDbConnection(GVar.OLE_DB_WRITE + testPath);
            dbTest.Open();

            cmd = new OleDbCommand(strCommand, dbTest);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First", first);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last", last);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Console.WriteLine("Data Added");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Db Test: " + ex.Message);
        }
        dbTest.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`OleDbCommand.Parameters` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example:
>
> SELECT * FROM
>   Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
>
> Therefore, the order in which
>   OleDbParameter objects are added to the OleDbParameterCollection must
>   directly correspond to the position of the question mark placeholder
>   for the parameter in the command text.

I don't see anything wrong in your `INSERT` statement other than this.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Identity ([First],[Last]) VALUES(?, ?)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First", first);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last", last);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a difference.  Is there something else I'm missing?

`cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Identity ([First],[Last]) VALUES(?, ?)";`

Comment: @johndoe86x Also you changed your parameters like `new OleDbParameter(?, first)` right? Actually, I didn't see any syntax error in your `INSERT` statement. What is your `cmd` looks like when you debug your code after you add parameter values?

Comment: I updated the OP to reflect my current code.  I also removed the try/catch statements so the program would break at the appropriate spot.
The unhandled exception still occurs at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: @johndoe86x Debug your code step by step and watch your `cmd` before your `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` line. And your `First` and `Last` columns are character type, right?

Comment: Something I noticed was that `rowArray` didn't seem to pull the values properly by using `new OleDbParameter("?", first)`.  I changed this to:
`OleDbParameter[] rowArray = new OleDbParameter[2];
rowArray[0].Value = first;
rowArray[1].Value = last;`
And now I'm getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Error on `rowArray[0].Value = first;`

Comment: @johndoe86x Then don't use array. Use `AddWithValue` or `AddValue` methods to add your parameter values. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and help.  It was greatly appreciated.  I've updated the OP to show the working solution.

Comment: @johndoe86x You are quite welcome. If this is solved your problem, don't forget to mark as an answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Yes, please change your answer to match my code in the OP, I used `@ColumnName` values rather than the question marks.